# Exchange ActiveSync does not work for one user

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, iphone, activesync

One particular user in our system is unable to connect to Exchange ActiveSync via her iPhone. When I try to connect using my own credentials on her iPhone it works (everything begins syncing), but when I input her credentials, the Settings app verifies the credentials are correct but nothing syncs. For example, if I open Mail, no items are shown. When I attempt to force a sync, it says "Cannot connect to server."

In Exchange 2010 Management Console the user is no different than the others. Exchange ActiveSync is set as "Enable" in Mailbox Features.

EDIT: Alternatively, if there is some easy way to create a new useraccount/mailbox and copy all of the contents of the old one over, I bet it would work, and that would be fine as well. She is a Mac user so we do not have to worry about her Active Directory account.

Comment: This link was very helpful for me.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.sdadminholder.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay the first thing to is to try https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

If a server error 500 occurs it might be related to the fact that the user is in a protected group, and thus some inheritance gets removed every hour..

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439375%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

To check whether inheritance is disabled on the user:

```
Open Active Directory Users and Computers.
On the menu at the top of the console, click View > Advanced Features.
Locate and right-click the mailbox account in the console, and then click Properties.
Click the Security tab.
Click Advanced.
Make sure that the check box for "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" is selected.
```

Try also to remove the phone from the mail user.

Comment: "Include inheritable permissions" did the trick.